# can I send mail from gmail address locally with PHP mail function?

Tags: php, email, gmail

the question is in the opening. Do I have to use googles SMTP, or can I get my mail to show up as if it was sent from me@gmail.com? I'm trying to send mass email and I'm pretty sure it would be annoying to do that through gmail's smtp.

Comment: As actual `Sender` or as `From` address? I strongly recommend (to avoid spam filters) to use a proper sender, and fiddle only with the `From` address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MIME headers `From` and `Reply-to` in the `mail();` function:

```
mail("receipient@somedomain.com", "subject", "body", "From: me@gmail.com
Reply-to: me@gmail.com");
```

But the receiver's mail-server will immediately notice that the point of origin and the address domain differ for that email, and there is a high chance of it being spammed.

Answer (score 1):

> But the receiver's mail-server will immediately notice that the point of origin and the address domain differ for that email, and there is a high chance of it being spammed.

This is not true. Receiver's e-mail server only cares if sender's SMTP server is on list of known spammer SMTP server (SORBS), it doesn't care about e-mail address has been set to mail header. So you can safely set From and Reply-to headers to myname@gmail.com email address and use your own ISP's SMTP server.

You may have problems if you are missing some relevant headers or your mail contains CAPS or words like FREE VIAGRA - in that case it may be marked as spam.

Actually, it seems like SORBS is not maintained anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, but it depends how if configured your local SMTP relay.

All you need in PHP is to set mime headers "From" and/or "Reply-to:" in mail.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the mail headers...

```
mail("aaa@aaa.com", "My subject", "My Msg", "From: Myself <bbb@bbb.com>\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will use gmail (smtp) you will be able to send limited number of email per some time other way you will be banned on it.
You can set up some local mail server but not all letters will be delivered and most of it will be marked as spam.